# Whats actually join() method is doing in Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpcontext

I have a doubt about join() in Thread. I want to get a session in Thread so I used it in my single thread. The first time I used it without join(), Unfortunately only for the first time I get the session value. But after using Join() it works fine. What is join doing in a single thread.    Here is the code I tried

```
public string ImportData(string entity, DataTable excelData, string dataExchangeSelectedColum, string conString, string fnameWithoutGuid, string loginName)
        {

            try
            {
                Guid importID = Guid.NewGuid();
                HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => { HttpContext.Current = ctx; ImportInThread(importID, entity, excelData, dataExchangeSelectedColum, conString, fnameWithoutGuid, loginName); });
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
                return importID.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }
```

Comment: is `ImportData` method is on a thread too?

Comment: @AvinashReddy no in thread there is a function called `ImportInThread`

Answer (score 2):

FYI: No *real* program should ever do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => { doStuff(); });
t.Start();
t.Join();
```

Calling `Join()` immediately after calling `Start()` defeats the purpose of creating the new thread. Instead of creating the new thread, the program could have simply called `doStuff()` at that point.

---

Create a new thread when you want to do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => { doStuff(); });
t.Start();
doOTHERStuff();
t.Join();
```

Now, you've got "Stuff" and "OTHERStuff" both happening concurrently, which is the entire purpose of threads.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Join()` blocks the calling threading until the thread you called `Join` on is finished.
In your case, it will wait until your code inside the thread is done then return the value of `importID`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => { HttpContext.Current = ctx; ImportInThread(importID, entity, excelData, dataExchangeSelectedColum, conString, fnameWithoutGuid, loginName); });
```

If you don't use `thread.Join()`, you're just starting and forgetting the thread.
This means you exit the method without knowing whether the thread finished or not, and you might need it to finish before you return.

For more infos: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: so if we are using a single thread it is necessary to join  thread?

Comment: @DhanilDinesan - No, it's not.

Comment: ok then why the Session is only get for the first time only when im not using  Join()?

Comment: @DhanilDinesan The HttpContext can only be used until the end of the processing of the request. If you don't call `Thread.Join`, then you immediately return, ending the processing of the request and leaving no chance to your background thread to access the HttpContext. If you want to access the session, you need to make sure to do so before ending the request

Comment: So if we use this `Thread.Join` in thread , there will be any performance issue?. because im using Thread for import excel and in sending multiple mails etc

Comment: Well I guess you're better off not using a thread if you're just waiting for it to end. A better solution would be to make the method async.